# Panzoom to element on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-transforms

I want the map of Disneyland to pan/zoom to the yellow square when you click on it. I'm new to web dev so any pointers on how to implement this with CSS/JavaScript/jQuery would be hugely appreciated.

**Edit:** I replaced my example with something closer to the actual app to avoid confusion.

**Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/dan-freeman/pen/mdVWYox

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://i.redd.it/64xwakxpbae21.jpg">
<div class="pin">Click me!</div>-
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
}

.pin {
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    top: 300px; /*Solution should use these coordinates*/
    left: 550px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Before Click**
[image]
**After Click**
[image]

Comment: @OP If you don't mind me asking, what did you use to generate those Chrome previews with the box shadow? It looks very nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example for your case. This literally solves your problem. You can give the scale size what you want in `.zoom` class. I gave it 1.5.

```js
const pins = document.querySelectorAll(".pin");
const figure = document.querySelector(".figure");
const mapImage = document.querySelector("#mapImage");

pins.forEach(p => {
  p.addEventListener("click", e => {

    figure.style.transformOrigin = `${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2}px ${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2}px`;


    if (figure.classList.contains("zoom")) {
      figure.style.transition = "transform-origin 0.3s, transform 0.3s";
    } else {
      figure.style.transition = "transform 0.3s";
    }

    figure.classList.add("zoom");
  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  pins.forEach((p) => {
    let isClickInside = p.contains(event.target);
    if (!isClickInside &&
      !event.target.classList.contains("pin")
    ) {
      figure.style.transition = "transform-origin 0.3s, transform 0.3s";
      figure.style.transformOrigin = '50% 50%';
      figure.classList.remove("zoom");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
}

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.pin1 {
  top: 300px;
  left: 550px;
}

.pin2 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 250px;
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure class="figure">
    <img id="mapImage" src="https://i.redd.it/64xwakxpbae21.jpg">

    <div class="pin pin1">Click me!</div>
    <div class="pin pin2">Another Pin</div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Another one:

```js
const pins = document.querySelectorAll(".pin");
const mapImage = document.querySelector("#mapImage");

pins.forEach(p => {
  p.addEventListener("click", e => {

    pins.forEach(pin => {
      pin.classList.remove("pinZoom");
    });

    mapImage.style.transformOrigin = `${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2}px ${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2}px`;


    if (mapImage.classList.contains("zoom")) {
      mapImage.style.transition = "transform-origin 0.3s, transform 0.3s";
    } else {
      mapImage.style.transition = "transform 0.3s";
    }


    mapImage.classList.add("zoom");
    p.classList.add("pinZoom");

  });
});

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  pins.forEach((p) => {
    let isClickInside = p.contains(event.target);
    if (!isClickInside &&
      !event.target.classList.contains("pin")
    ) {
      mapImage.style.transformOrigin = '50% 50%';
      mapImage.classList.remove("zoom");
      p.classList.remove("pinZoom");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
figure{
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.pin1 {
  top: 300px;
  left: 550px;
}

.pin2 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 250px;
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.pinZoom {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img id="mapImage" src="https://i.redd.it/64xwakxpbae21.jpg">
</figure>

<div class="pin pin1">Click me!</div>
<div class="pin pin2">Another Pin</div>
```

I created another example also with [js-image-zoom](https://github.com/malaman/js-image-zoom) library and no click needed. You can set scale, zoom position, offset, zoom width and zoom style. See documentation.

```js
var options = {
  width: 800,
  zoomWidth: 800,
  /*
  offset: {
    vertical: 0,
    horizontal: 10
  },
  scale: 2.0,
  */
  zoomPosition: 'original', /* right, top, bottom, left */
};

new ImageZoom(document.getElementById("img-container"), options);
```

```css
.pin {
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  top: 300px;
  left: 550px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#img-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-container" style="width: 400px">
  <img src="https://i.redd.it/64xwakxpbae21.jpg" />
<div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-image-zoom@0.7.0/js-image-zoom.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is pretty cool but in my case I need the container to actually snap to the yellow boxes that represent points of interest, not just track the mouse

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something as simple as a javacript adding css upon click will do...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.transform = 'translate(-500px,-250px) scale(3)';
```

I believe you would still have to manually tweak the `translate` parameters. Check it out:
https://codepen.io/pen/jOWamjL

Comment: This is pretty elegant. Do you know if there's a way to select a transformation (-500px,-250px) on the box coordinates (300px, 550px)?

Comment: The way i did it was: i took 50px off of the `left` and the `top` properties of the pin div, then multiplied by `-1`. I don't know if it would work for every pin you would need - I'd be careful with pins close to the borders.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael. I ended up awarding the bounty to dgknca because I'm more comfortable with CSS but I think this is a very elegant solution as well

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="big">
            <div class="small"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

let small = document.querySelector('.small')

let shiftX = null
let shiftY = null

let getCoords = (elem) => { 
    let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect()
      return {
        top: box.top + pageYOffset,
        left: box.left + pageXOffset
      }
   }
}

small.addEventListener('mousedown', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  small.classList.add('test')
  small.style.position = 'absolute'
  let coords = getCoords(small)
  let shiftX = evt.pageX - coords.left
  let shiftY = evt.pageY - coords.top
})

small.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  small.style.left = evt.pageX - shiftX + 'px'
  small.style.top = evt.pageY - shiftY + 'px'
})

small.addEventListener('mouseup', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  small.classList.remove('test')
})

.test {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: In this case I need the blue square to actually zoom/pan to the green square similar to the way Google Maps zoom/pans to specific locations when you tap on them. It looks like this script is just making the green square bigger.

Comment: mm, your need drag and drop

Comment: I'm not familiar with that feature

Comment: I don't want to drag and drop the square, I want to zoom in on it

Answer (score -1):

you need to add an evenement "click" with Jquery and toggle class "expend" for exemple to add style to your square :

https://codepen.io/ZellRDesign/pen/NWxpmdd

```js
var square = $(".square")

square.click(function(){
  console.log("salut")
  square.toggleClass("expend")
})
```

```css
.square{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: .3s;
} 

.square.expend{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="square"></div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like this snippet is just making the square bigger, in my app I need to div to actually zoom in on it